# How to create a NumPy array of booleans with k% True values?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I know that we can create a NumPy array of boolean values with the following line of code:

```
np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(N,))
```

But what if I want to specify that I want this random array to have around 60% (or more generally k%) **True** values?

Comment: [choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) take a `p` value, so you can set `p=[0.4, 0.6]`

Answer (score 3):

Use the probabilities array argument of [`np.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

```
import numpy as np

N = 100
res = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(N,), p=[0.4, 0.6])
print(np.count_nonzero(res))
```

**Output** (of a single run)

```
62
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `np.random.choice` can be really slow for large arrays. I recommend doing

```py
import numpy as np
N = 100_000
booleans = np.random.rand(N) < 0.6
```

`np.random.rand` will produce uniform random numbers between `0.0` and `1.0`, and the comparison will set all numbers under `0.6` to `True`, giving you an array with roughly 60% `True` values.

If you need exactly the proportion you're asking for, you can do this

```
k = 60  # 60%
booleans = np.zeros(shape=(N,), dtype=bool) # Array with N False
booleans[:int(k / 100 * N)] = True  # Set the first k% of the elements to True
np.random.shuffle(booleans)  # Shuffle the array

np.count_nonzero(booleans)  # Exactly 60 000 True elements
```